# How to set the system time using assembly 8086 with dosbox?

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

I wish to set the system time, and get the time for display. i have successfully get he system time with the following code

```
mov ah,2ch              ;get time
int 21h                 ;ch = hr, cl = min, dh = sec
```

but i cannot set the system time, by following 2 methods

```
mov ah,03h

mov ch,hr(in bcd)
mov cl,mm(in bcd)
mov dh,sec(in bcd)
mov dl,am_pm

int 1ah
```

and

```
mov ah,2dh
mov ch,hr
mov cl,mm
mov dh,sec
int 21h
```

Comment: How did you check to see if the time changed?  Did you run `data` in the DOS shell after your program exited?  Or use your get-time program?  You realize this will only set the time inside the one instance of DOSBOX or emu8086 virtual machine where you ran set-time, right, not your main system's time (Windows/Linux/OS X)?

Comment: Oops, I meant `date`, not `data`.  Or I guess in DOS the command is `time`.

Comment: i use code to get the time and display in the dosbox, but the result is 00:00:00, i think  you were right it doesnt change the system time. So i wish to know to to get the time that i have changed?

Comment: Are you sure you're printing it correctly, or setting the right time (if 00:00:00 was unexpected)?  Use a debugger!  And post a [mcve].

Comment: The BIOS RTC and system time aren't necessarily in sync.  The RTC is what keeps the time while the computer is off, separate from the software time counter in RAM updated on timer interrupts.  Make sure you're checking the one you're setting.  http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah2b says that `int 21h / ah=2Bh` does also set the CMOS time (RTC) on DOS 3.3+.

Comment: So do you know what code should i use in order to reset the time by user and display it in dosbox, not necessary must sync with system time. thanks !

Comment: From the docs it looks like `int 21h / AH=2Dh` should work.  If it isn't working for you, post a [mcve] of exactly what you did.

Answer (score -1):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
.CODE
START: MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

;Hour Part
HOUR:
MOV AH,2CH    ; To get System Time
INT 21H
MOV AL,CH     ; Hour is in CH
AAM
MOV BX,AX
CALL DISP

MOV DL,':'
MOV AH,02H    ; To Print : in DOS
INT 21H

;Minutes Part
MINUTES:
MOV AH,2CH    ; To get System Time
INT 21H
MOV AL,CL     ; Minutes is in CL
AAM
MOV BX,AX
CALL DISP

MOV DL,':'    ; To Print : in DOS
MOV AH,02H
INT 21H

;Seconds Part
Seconds:
MOV AH,2CH    ; To get System Time
INT 21H
MOV AL,DH     ; Seconds is in DH
AAM
MOV BX,AX
CALL DISP


;To terminate the Program

MOV AH,4CH     ; To Terminate the Program
INT 21H

;Display Part
DISP PROC
MOV DL,BH      ; Since the values are in BX, BH Part
ADD DL,30H     ; ASCII Adjustment
MOV AH,02H     ; To Print in DOS
INT 21H
MOV DL,BL      ; BL Part 
ADD DL,30H     ; ASCII Adjustment
MOV AH,02H     ; To Print in DOS
INT 21H
RET
DISP ENDP      ; End Disp Procedure


END START      ; End of MAIN
```

Try this wotking finely

Comment: The OP is looking to set the time, they know how to get it.

Comment: means he need the live display of time then...

Comment: No what he means is that he wants to be able to set the time to a specific value of hours minutes and seconds.  You are only displaying the number not setting it. The OP also says in thw question they already know how to get the time.

Comment: got it he wants to change the system time itself.